# Summing a series - Calculus 1.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm learning Calculus 1 at the collage,

and the semester's end is close, which bring with it the exams period.

So I pretty much understand all the topics,

except for a series summing.

I don't know why, but I just don't get it. I Googled a lot, but nothing. so I hope to find my luck here.

For example, I have the following series:

${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}} ({1\over 2^{n-1}})$.

I need a detailed explanation, how to sum this series. Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In mathematics, a geometric series is a series with a constant ratio between successive terms. For example, the series

$1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{8}+\dfrac{1}{16}+ \ldots$

is geometric, because each successive term can be obtained by multiplying the previous term by $\frac {1}{2} $

In general the sum of a geometric series with the first term 'a' and common ratio 'r' is given by :. $$ S=\frac{a (1-r^n)}{1-r} $$

Suppose, $|r|<1 $ ie. $-1<r<1$ and $n$ tends to $\infty$, we can say that $r^n$ tends to $0$ (why?)

Hence, the sum becomes $$ S=\frac {a}{1-r} $$

Here, the first term is 1. the common ratio is $\frac {1
}{2} $ (Observe)

substituting, we get, $$ S=\frac {1}{1-\frac{1}{2}} $$
so, $S=2$

Comment: What does "common ratio" mean? and how did you get it?

Comment: Common ratio is that quantity we multiply with each term to obtain the next term

Comment: Here, your series is 1 + 1/2 + 1/4.... Each term is obtained by multiplying 1/2 with the previous term

Comment: I didn't get it yet .. can you please edit your post and be more detailed? thank you..

Comment: sure. Are you familiar with geometric series?

Comment: I am. thanks again!

Comment: hope you understand

Comment: I do. really appreciate this. thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) is? Your series is simply:
$$
1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{8}+\dfrac{1}{16}+ \ldots
$$
with common ratio $r=1/2$ whose first term is $t_1=1$. Since $|r|<1$, it will converge to:
$$
\dfrac{t_1}{1-r} = \dfrac{1}{1-1/2} = \dfrac{2}{2-1} = 2
$$

Comment: It took awhile to understand but it has understood. thanks

Answer (score 0):

when we expand , this is the series that we obtain,

$1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{8}+\dfrac{1}{16}+ \ldots$goes upto 0.

this is an infinite geometric progression.

For any GP, sum upto "n" terms is given by $S=\frac {a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$, but when n tends to infinity as in this case the formula can be modified

as $S=\frac{a}{1-r}$ -(1)- ,

where 'a' represents the first term and 'r' represents the ratio by which any term is multiplied to get the next consecutive term, in this case the common ratio ratio is $\frac {1}{2} $
because,

consider the first term '1' and when we multiply the first term by $\frac {1}{2} $ we get the second term, i.e  $\frac {1}{2} $, like wise when we multiply the second term  $\frac {1}{2} $ with   $\frac {1}{2} $ we get the third term  $\frac {1}{4} $and it goes on.

Therefore on applying the values of 'a' and 'r' in equation -(1)- we get S=2.